# How to grab the url or path of generated docs created in phpdocx

Tags: phpdocx

We have a project in which we are using phpdocx in generating word document. We would like to grab the url or path of the generated docs and send it to email. How can we grab the url? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you generate docs, you pass $path parameter to the method createdocx() like this:

```
<?php   

    $docx = new CreateDocx();

    $docx->addText('This is just a dummy text');

    $docx->createDocx($path);

?>
```

This generate the document at $path. So you always have the path of the generated docs